# Remove Braces and Double Quotes from array

Tags: android, arrays

In my Application i am saving Contacts in SharedPreferences but the array which i am passing is also including open braces and double Quotes in the string.

like this ["contactnumber1","contactnumber2","contactnumber3".......]

but i need the string to be like this
contactnumber1,contactnumber2,contactnumber3....

so that i can use this contactnumbers string to directly place it in sms app and send alert msg with click of a button.

please help me with this

Code:

```
    String[] arrayOfString=localMultiAutoCompleteTextview.getText().toString().split(",");

// Create a JSONArray to store all numbers
            JSONArray numberArray=new JSONArray();

// Loop through the multiautocomplete textview value array
            for(int i=0; i < arrayOfString.length; i++)
            {
                // Check whether the string contains '%'
                if(arrayOfString[i].contains("%"))
                {
                    // Add numbers to the array
                    numberArray.put(arrayOfString[i].split("%")[1]);
                }
            }

// Store the complete number array in preference as String
            sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sdat", 2);
            ed=sp.edit();
            ed.putString("snum", numberArray.toString());
            ed.commit();


// To read the numbers after saving
            String display = sp.getString("snum", new JSONArray().toString());
            System.out.println(display);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Contacts Saved:"+display,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't store strings in an array without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is a regex which matches quotes and brackets, and removes them from the string. Just call `replaceAll` and it will go through your string, find the following characters: '[', ']', '"' and remove them from the string.

```
strWithoutQuotesAndBraces = strWithQuotesAndBraces.replaceAll("(["[\\]])", "");
```

Comment: how can i call it in my code plz tell me... as actualli i am storing the string in shared preferences. when and where should  i add the above replaceAll  .